# Keeping last part of field only in logstash

Tags: logstash

How can I trim to only the last part of a key in logstash?

I have URLs formatted in the form of `http://aaa.bbb/get?a=1&b=2`, putting them into 'request' and splitting the field based on '?&' to save the GET parameters.

I care only about the specific API call, and not the host or protocol. What filter(s) can I chain to keep only the part after the final '/'? I've read up a bit on patterns but haven't stumbled upon how to reference the last part of a split field.

```
        grok {
            match => [ "message", "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp} 
%{NOTSPACE:loadbalancer} %{IP:client_ip}:%{NUMBER:client_port:int}
%{IP:backend_ip}:%{NUMBER:backend_port:int} 
%{NUMBER:request_processing_time:float}
%{NUMBER:backend_processing_time:float} 
%{NUMBER:response_processing_time:float} 
%{NUMBER:elb_status_code:int}
%{NUMBER:backend_status_code:int} 
%{NUMBER:received_bytes:int} %{NUMBER:sent_bytes:int} 
%{QS:request}" ]
        }
    date {
        match => [ "timestamp", "ISO8601" ]
    }

    kv {
        field_split => "&?"
        source => "request"
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest taking the existing URI-related patterns and modifying them to your needs.  You will note that URIPATHPARAM parses out the URIPATH and URIPARAM but doesn't shove them into fields.

So, make your own URIPATHPARAM:

```
MYURIPATHPARM  URIPATHPARAM %{URIPATH:uripath}(?:%{URIPARAM:uriparam})?
```

and then call it from your own URI:

```
MYURI URI %{URIPROTO}://(?:%{USER}(?::[^@]*)?@)?(?:%{URIHOST})?(?:%{MYURIPATHPARAM})?
```

In your previous grok{}, you ended up with %{request}.  Make a new grok{} that runs [request] through MYURI, and you should end up with the two fields that you're after.

Comment: Thanks Alain. I was looking at the problem from the wrong direction. I wound up using the following: match => [ "request"], "%{WORD:verb}\s%{URIPROTO}://%{URIHOST}%{URIPATH:path}%{URIPARAM:params}\s%{GREEDYDATA}"]

Comment: that should be: match => [ "request", "%{WORD:verb}\s%{URIPROTO}://%{URIHOST}%{URIPATH:path}%{URIPARAM:params}\s%{GREE‌​DYDATA}"]